# How fast would a paddle have to move through water to create a vacuum behind it?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, thermodynamics

If a paddle, or any object, moves through water it will of course create a drag behind it. I am wondering if there would be a vacuum created in case the paddle moves very fast and how fast the paddle would have to be to create such room.

Using the average velocity for ideal gases I found that a water molecule would move at 650 m/s, which sounds very high, especially since a lot of the molecules would move higher than this number, considering the velocity distribution of such gases.

So how can the average velocity of water be found or can it be found? And is my train of thought correct or am I missing something?

Comment: See 'cavitation'...

Comment: @JonCuster would it be possible to calculate this without regards to cavitation? Is there a speed that would be so high that even the cavitation can be overcome?

Comment: What do you mean, "overcome?" Cavitation _is_ the phenomenon that you are asking about. Cavitation _is_ the answer to your question. P.S., in engineering, in cases where cavitation is undesirable, sometimes the solution to the problem is not to eliminate the cavitation, but to _enhance_ it: In so-called [_supercavitating_](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supercavitation) systems, the vapor bubble is so big, that it does not collapse against the propellor/turbine/etc., and therefore, it does no damage.

Comment: @SolomonSlow what I mean is, the bubbles that would build are water vapor. But they also need to form on the edges of the object and stream into the area behind the object, if the object would move with incredible speed, could there even be a vacuum and not just water vapor created?

Comment: The propeller blade or other obstacle would have to be moving relative to the vapor in the bubble at greater than the speed of sound within the vapor. Given that it would have to push liquid water out of its way to do so, I think that making it actually happen would be a Herculean engineering project.

Comment: @SolomonSlow thanks! well, its not about if its possible or not.